# How to keep Activity alive when its parent activity gets destroyed

Tags: android, android-activity

I launch activity A from activity B . But as I launch A , B gets Destroyed.
As a result A gets displayed momentarily and then gets destroyed . 
How do i keep A alive even after B is destroyed.
This is how i launch A from B.

```
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        intent.setClass(B.this, A.class);

        intent.putExtra(key, val);
        startActivity(intent);
```

I have mentioned the launchmode for Activity A in the manifest file as 'singleTask'.

Please help me how to achieve this .

Comment: you set flag for intent to FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP, that means activity A is clear from stack, and when Activity B start there is no record of activity A.

Comment: @Divyesh so you mean i should remove the Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP from above code.

Comment: yes you shoud remove flags.

Comment: I do not undertstand your point , Activity B startA , then B gets destroyed . 
So your point "Activity B start there is no record of activity A" what does it mean

Comment: Activity A will not be destroyed when it is on screen. There should not happen anything to A even B is destroyed. What did you do in Activity A?

Comment: @AssIstne i am creating a listview in A . I get the logs from Android , that Activity A is displayed.
And if its parent is destroyed why should A not get destroyed?

Comment: @PardeepKr Because of the lifecycle of Activity.When user is active in Activity A, then A will never be destroyed.

Comment: @Asslstne thanks . Your comments helped . I found the problem .

Answer (score 1):

Actvity B is destroyed due to the flag `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP`, but doesnt affect activity A life cycle. Meaning that if Activity A its being destroyed it might be  some error in its own life cycle method but its not chained to Activity B